# How does google Spark-BigQuery-Connector leverage BigQuery Storage API?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataproc

According to https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/connectors/bigquery the connector uses BigQuery Storage API to read data using gRPC. However, I couldn't find any Storage API/gRPC usage in the source code here: https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/spark-bigquery-connector/tree/master/connector/src/main/scala

My questions are:
1. could anyone show me the source code where uses storage API & gprc call?
2. Does `Dataset<Row> df =  session.read().format("bigquery").load()` work through GBQ storage API? if not, how to read from GBQ to Spark using BigQuery Storage API?

Comment: do you mean how to use it? if so, looking at the [examples](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/tutorials/bigquery-connector-spark-example) and [examples folder](https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/spark-bigquery-connector/blob/master/connector/src/main/scala/com/google/cloud/spark/bigquery/examples/Shakespeare.scala) is always the natural choice. If not I misunderstood your question, which I guess is the case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Spark BigQuery Connector uses only BigQuery Storage API for reads, you can see it [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/spark-bigquery-connector/blob/f4b95ebb28ea28638cee04afc6a6f666f3e2abff/connector/src/main/scala/com/google/cloud/spark/bigquery/direct/BigQueryRDD.scala#L19), for example.
2. Yes, `Dataset<Row> df =  session.read().format("bigquery").load()` works through BigQuery Storage API.